# EF6 get simple list from DB that is not context dependent

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

its late and I apologize if I've missed something obvious

I have a WPF / Entity Framework 6 application (which is also mvvm).

In this application I have a class(viewmodel) that opens two contexts:

1. the first context stays open for a unit of work process connected to the class/viewmodel
2. the second context is temporary and is sues to get 4-5 different "lists" from the DB for use in static comboboxes.

The first context will get disposed and recreated to ensure that the records in that context are up to date from the database.

### MY PROBLEM:

I can't use the temporary context for the lists because I get the following error when I use the list as the ItemSource for a custom AutoComplete TextBox that filters the records.

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used
> for operations that require a connection.

I can't use the main context because it also will get disposed to ensure the records are up to date.

**Example of contexts:**(_ModelService just returns a new EF6 context)

```
Context = _ModelService.NewContext
Jobs = Await _JobService.GetJobActive_AllAsync(Context)

Using tempContext = _ModelService.NewContext
    ChangeOrders = Await _JobService.GetJobChange_AllAsync(tempContext)
End Using
```

### SOLUTIONS?:

I need a way to get the most recent records from the db in EF6 without disposing of the context and recreating it

**OR**

I need to be able to built a static list from the context records that once created no longer needs the context but exists within the class.

I hope this makes sense,
Thanks in advance

### EDIT # 1:

For Anthony - the GetJobChange_AllAsync method:

```
Public Async Function GetJobActive_AllAsync(Context As FTC_Context) As Task(Of ObservableCollection(Of job)) Implements IJobDataService.GetJobActive_AllAsync
            Try
                Dim joblist = Await Context.jobs.Where(Function(openjob) openjob.idStatus = 1).ToListAsync
                Return New ObservableCollection(Of job)(joblist)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return Nothing
            End Try
        End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You could detach the objects from the context. You can have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.data.objects.objectcontext.detach(v=vs.100).aspx

To loose the reference to the context you also might use AsNoTracking: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: Okay,  SO I tried the serialization method, it generated problems as my base class is not serializable and I did not want to make it so.  I will try the detach method

Comment: It looks like in EF 6 there is no detach, but AsNoTracking should be used to achieve the same function

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing how `GetJobChange_AllAsync()` is implemented, it sounds like it might return an IEnumerable or IQueryable, and execution is deferred until the lists are accessed (after tempContext is disposed). Try to use `ToList()` to execute the query while the context is still valid...

```
Using tempContext = _ModelService.NewContext
    ChangeOrders = (Await _JobService.GetJobChange_AllAsync(tempContext)).ToList()
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks,  I tired exactly that and it did not wwork.  I included the GetJobChange_AllAsync() in the original post

Comment: What does the `job` entity look like?

Comment: the job entity is generated by the EF .tt - its rather long and I extend it with a partial class that implements error validation.  do you want me to post the partial class or the generated class?

Comment: Does it have any navigation properties? If it does, use `Include()` in your query to eager load them.